# C++ Copying elements into new list

Tags: c++, list

I have a problem with copying some elements of list into the new one. It has to be done under one condition: elements that can be copied must be from entered range. The problem is that every single element is copied into newlist. Any suggestions? I want to note that my English is not perfect but I hope you gonna get it. Thank you :)

```
struct Node
{
    Node* next;
    int data;
};

struct List
{
    Node* head;
    Lista();
    void push(int);
    void addafter(int, int);
    void delchosen(int);
    void pop();
    void print();
    int count();
    Node* find(int);
    void pushback(int);
    void popback();
    void minmax(int&, int&);
    List* range(int, int);
};

List::List()
{
     head = NULL;
}
void List::push(int value)
{
     Node *p = new Node;
     p->data = value;
     p->next = head;
     head = p;
}
List* List::range(int x, int y)
{
    Node* e = head;
    List* newlist = new List;

    while(e)
    {
        if(e->data > x && e->data <y)
        {
            newlist->push(e->data);
        }
        e = e->next;
    }
    return newlist;
}

int main()
{
    List l;
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int size = 30;
    int* arr = new int [size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
        arr[i]=rand()%20+1; 
        l.push(arr[i]);
        }
    l.range(3, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Didn't think it will be necessary, but I just have edited the code. Every single function works fine excepting this copying.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Michał Habigier First of all I di not see where the original list is filled with values. As for the function then it is valid provided that the default constructor and member function push are also valid.

Comment: How do you know what's inside the list?

Comment: It's obvious that there will be at least one element from range 3 to 10. But in my whole code I pushed in main some elements from this range e.g. 4, 5, 9.

Comment: By using push function of course.

Comment: The question was "How do you find out what values are inside the new list?". I meant not your theoretical reasoning or expectations, but a real debug watch or print results. The memory content. In fact, your code is fine, you just watching/printing old list. That's why you see all the values. In the code above you never use the resulting sublist and even never assign it to a variable.

Comment: Thank you for help and the tips. Everything comes out from lack of self-confidence of my skills :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use the new list. That could probably mislead you. For example you could print or watch in the debugger the old list, which is still contain all the values. It happens sometimes with all the programmers, from freshmen to old long-bearded gurus.

Otherwise code should work:

```
auto newList = l.range(3, 10);
newList->print();
```

**Bonus: General code review.**

- It would probably be easier to debug and test the code if you fill the list with deterministic values, rather than random content:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      l.push(i);
  }
  ```
- Most likely you don't need to allocate `newlist` on the heap. Use stack allocation:

  ```
  List List::range(int x, int y) const {
      ...

          List newlist;
      ...
          newlist.push(...);
      ...
          return newlist;
  }
  ```
- While it's nice and funny for self-education and various hacking, you should avoid using homebrew linked lists in the serious code. In C++ we tend to use Standard library facilities instead. Something like:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iterator>
  #include <list>

  int main() {
      // Construct original list from brace-initializer list
      std::list<int> original{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

      // Get the beginning of the new list by advancing
      //          beginning of the original list by 2 elements
      auto begin = original.cbegin();
      std::advance(begin, 2);

      // Get the end of the new list by advancing
      //          beginning of the original list by 5 elements
      auto end = original.cbegin();
      std::advance(end, 5);

      // Construct sublist  from iterator range
      std::list<int> sublist(begin, end);

      // Print new list
      for (auto&& e : sublist)
          std::cout << e << ' '; // prints "3 4 5"
  }
  ```

Comment: That helped me a lot! Obviously I'm gonna use it in future but for now I need to pass an exam - algorithms and data structures. Thus I can't use C++ libraries right now.